# Whats' the meaning of "promote points of commonality"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence, what's the meaning of "promote points of commonality"?
Does it mean something like that governments play a role as a mediator and find a central points where opposite sides can agree upon altogether?

> As young sharing economies evolve, government may play several roles.
> First, where industry members’ interests are not aligned or where a
> large number of market competitors exists, governments can facilitate
> discussion, mobilize the public, and **promote points of commonality.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we decipher “promote points of commonality,” let’s understand what the rest of the text means.

Essentially, the author is writing about **what to do when a young/developing industry becomes too competitive or the members’ interests differ.**

---

Now, we can start to decipher “points of commonality.”

By looking at the antithesis of this phrase, we can discover it’s meaning.

The phrase “point of difference” is quite common and refers to a capability that someone (or their business) has that **is unique and can differentiate themselves from their competitors.**

Now, it becomes quite clear that “point of commonality” refers to **a capability that is shared among competitors in an industry.**

---

> Does it mean something like that governments play a role as a mediator and find a central points where opposite sides can agree upon altogether?

**Yes, it essentially means that governments should try to advance the common capabilities and interests of members in developing industries to ensure that it (the industry) evolves smoothly.**